# Pulling from a sourcerepo mercurial repository slows down as the history increases. Why, and is there a solution?

Tags: mercurial

**The Problem**

Pulling changes from our Sourcerepo mercurial repository used to take very little time, e.g. a couple of seconds. Now it takes enough time for me to go get a drink and have a wee (a few minutes).  It is getting incrementally slower as, I presume, a function of the size of the history on the repository.  This is really annoying, there's only so much drinking and weeing I need to do, it's starting to hit my productivity.

**Context**

- The repo is on [Sourcerepo](http://sourcerepo.com/).
- I'm connecting to the repo over ssh SSH with key based authentication.
- I'm using TortoiseHG as my tool of choice, though the issue is equally seen via the command line.
- It takes a long time to check for incoming changesets, it's the pull not the
  update that's taking the time.
- If there are no changes it only takes a few seconds to tell me that.
- We use a lot of named branches, we do close them after ourselves so there's 5-20 open at a time but hundreds in the history.
- We've got a little under 3k revisions in the repo.
- Pushing is still really fast.

I thought Hg used some sort of delta encoding to only get the changes, it shouldn't be taking this long.  I wondered if there was an option I was missing in Hg or if anyone else has experienced this behaviour?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Has somebody added something really large to the repository perhaps?  We have over 5,000 revisions in our Mercurial repository without the problems that you are describing.  We have our own on-site Mercurial server but I don't have any problems when I connect from home over the VPN either.

Comment: Is there something funny about your repo? A huge number of heads, for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

- `hg incoming -v --time --profile --debug REPO-URL` and read output - it can shed some light on most slow parts in process
- Clone Sourcerepo to *local* repository and test incoming against this repo (eliminate network-related latency)

If nothing help

- clone smaller parts of repo (from 1 to tip) and test incoming for these truncated clones in order to identify changeset (I hope), which brings this headache: I can't see how to use bisect on single big repo for test `incoming` operational time